# What does is this Error Log from PhoneGap Build trying to tell me (iOS build -Android ok)

Tags: ios, build, phonegap

For a little while I have been successfully testing my App with Android and all is good - I finally got the courage to tackle Apple Certification and finally got all the documentation to a point where I could submit a Build request to Cloud Build. Unfortunately it has failed and I have no idea why (sorry, don't understand a word of the Log).

The PhoneGap App details are ......
App ID: 3345282
Version:    5.0.1

PhoneGap (iOS / Android / Windows): cli-8.0.0 (4.5.4 / 7.0.0 / 5.0.0)
Source: .zip package

and the final (hopefully the relevant) lines of the log are ...

Ld /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ephalump-dugkldzlmaztzpbpvjaewqbnuywf/Build/Intermed iates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Ephalump/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Ephalump.build/Rel e ase-iphoneos/Ephalump.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Ephalump normal armv7

```
cd /project

export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0

/Applications/Xcode92.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode92.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/i PhoneOS11.2.sdk -L/project/build -F/project/build -F/project/Pods/OneSignal/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Framework -filelist /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ephalump-dugkldzlmaztzpbpvjaewqbnuywf/Build/Intermed iates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Ephalump/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Ephalump.build/Rel e ase-iphoneos/Ephalump.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Ephalump.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ephalump-dugkldzlmaztzpbpvjaewqbnuywf/Build/Intermed iates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Ephalump/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Ephalump.build/Rel e ase-iphoneos/Ephalump.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Ephalump_lto.o -Xlinker -final_output -Xlinker /Applications/Ephalump.app/Ephalump -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -ObjC -framework OneSignal -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework UserNotifications -ObjC -framework OneSignal -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework UserNotifications /project/build/libCordova.a -framework SystemConfiguration -lPods-Ephalump -weak_framework ImageIO -framework CoreLocation -framework AVFoundation -weak_framework AddressBook -weak_framework AddressBookUI -lz -framework CoreMotion -weak_framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreTelephony -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ephalump-dugkldzlmaztzpbpvjaewqbnuywf/Build/Intermed iates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Ephalump/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Ephalump.build/Rel e ase-iphoneos/Ephalump.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Ephalump_dependency_info.dat -o /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ephalump-dugkldzlmaztzpbpvjaewqbnuywf/Build/Intermed iates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Ephalump/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Ephalump.build/Rel e ase-iphoneos/Ephalump.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Ephalump
```

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

```
Ld /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ephalump-dugkldzlmaztzpbpvjaewqbnuywf/Build/Intermed iates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Ephalump/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Ephalump.build/Rel e ase-iphoneos/Ephalump.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Ephalump normal arm64
```

(1 failure)

Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/private/project/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-workspace,Ephalump.xcworkspace ,-scheme,Ephalump,-configuration,Release,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,E p halump.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/private/project/build/device,SHARED_PRE C OMPS_DIR=/private/project/build/sharedpch

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO :) Did you really want to post your email address in the question description? I'd advise removing it, since it doesn't add anything to the question. Have you tried building the project locally using Xcode? If you're using Phonegapbuild, maybe you don't have a Mac, but I'd strongly suggest trying to get hold of one and see what happens when you compile locally. It's much less of a black box than Phonegapbuild! Hope this helps.

Comment: I might add... these are very general xcodebuild errors, and the chances of anyone being able to help you solve them without more logs are fairly remote. Do you have any technical support available through Phonegap? If so, I recommend raising this as a support ticket and seeing if they can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - you are correct, I am using PhoneGap as while I have access to a Mac, I have zero knowledge of it and I don't know how to transfer the project onto it or how to compile locally using Xcode :(   Anybody willing to bear with me to teach me?

Comment: Does Phonegap build give you the option to download a zip archive of the whole project?